# What is the meaning of the (seemingly) noun word "claw-catch" in a poem?

Tags: meaning, poetry, literature

From "[God's Secretary](http://www.poetryoutloud.org/poem/182573)" by R.S. Gwynn:

> Her e-mail inbox always overflows.
>   Her outbox doesn’t get much use at all.
>   She puts on hold the umpteen-billionth call
>   As music oozes forth to placate those
>   Who wait, then disconnect. Outside, wind blows,
>   Scything pale leaves. She sees a sparrow fall
>   Fluttering to a **claw-catch** on a wall.
>   Will He be in today? God only knows.

I googled for "claw-catch" and "clawcatch", found one sense to be a kind of [a movement](http://juggle.wikia.com/wiki/Claw) in juggling, that doesn't seem to fit.

Maybe what's meant here is some small crevice or other uneven feature of the wall allowing the sparrow to catch it with its claws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: birds clinging to the side of a brick wall]

I think you're right - a claw-catch seems to mean a place a bird can cling to.